# Choosing the right methodology for developing a system such as Control Monitoring System

Tags: c#, methodology, rup, rational-unified-process

I want to know the scope of the sufficient impact of the RUP methodology. i know it would be so efficient in on IS Systems such as MIS and HIS and so on but when you want to design and develop a system such as Control Monitoring System, is it be so sufficient as good as IS system. I mean when most challenges on such systems would be technical not rational, relational and informational that RUP is focussed on, is that be still so efficient as well. and if isn't, what methodologies you suggest instead of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defence industry often uses some variant of MIL-STD-498 or its successor IEEE 12207. These are more technically oriented than RUP and less concerned with, well, selling consultants for Rational quite frankly.